# Data not saved in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

Data not saved in database.This is Stripe Api, Code is below
How can I save in database through stripe API? If data saved in database than it is correct way to collect payment?
Stripe Api payment secure?

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PaymentLogs;
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    //
     public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth'); // if you want user to be logged in to use this function then uncomment this code.
    }
    
    public function handleonlinepay(Request $request){  
        
        $input = $request->input();
        try {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));                   
                // Insert into the database
                PaymentLogs::create([                                         
                    'amount'=> $input['amount'],
                    'plan'=> $input['plan'],
                    'charge_id'=>$charge->id,
                    'stripe_id'=>$unique_id,                     
                    'quantity'=>1
                ]);

                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Charge successful, Thank you for payment!',
                    'state' => 'success'
                ]);                
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'There were some issue with the payment. Please try again later.',
                    'state' => 'error'
                ]);
            }             
                
    }
}
```

Error is

{
    "message": "There were some issue with the payment. Please try again later.",
    "state": "error"
}

Comment: do you fill the `protected $fillable` in your MODEL ?

Comment: yes I fill -@Rezash

Comment: I think problem in javascript, but i did not created view file than where is put javascript? It is API so -@Rezash

Comment: please send me what type of error you are getting?